# How to import a class from a different package in the present package in python?

Tags: python

I have created a package in pycharm by the name "Classes in python". How can I use a class of that package in a separate package? I am using the statement "import classes in python.MyDate" and I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are getting a syntax error, to import your class with name 'Point' from a module named 'xx' just type:
`from xx import Point`